# unable to get hidden field value using parent 's class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code is-

```
<tr class="selected">
<td id="participantID">XXXXX1234</td>
<input type="hidden" value="000001234" id="taxID">
<td id="fullName">Y, X</td>
</tr>
```

Here, I want to get hidden field value. I can not use ID of hidden field to get its value because there are multiple rows which can contain hidden field with same ID as "taxID". I want to get this value using `<tr>` class name.
i.e. selected.

I am using below code to get its value but it is giving me 'undefined' value.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[0];
var y = x.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
alert(y.value);
```

Alert statement shows undefined value. Am I missing something over here?

Comment: *'there are multiple rows which can contain hidden field with same ID as "taxID"'* -- ID's need to be unique

Comment: Your HTML is also invalid. The `input` cannot be a child of the `tr`

Comment: first of ID should be unique. use selector like `$(".selected").find("input:hidden')`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quick response. I will remove that id. But how to get that hidden field value using class name?

Comment: @Nitesh you need to fix your HTML first before anyone can give you an informed answer. If you have multiple inputs of that type, they could share a class name and have unique IDs. Once you do this, please post an update to your question and someone will be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. After removing that ID. It is working fine.

Comment: @Nitesh That's good, but you still have other problems that should be corrected. See my answer below for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you cannot have multiple elements in a document with identical `id` values. That will have to be altered and that alone may solve your problem.

Second, your HTML is invalid. The `input` must be *inside* of a `td`.

Next, there is no reason to use `getElementsByClassName()` or `getElementsByTagName()` when you are looking for just one element - it's wasteful because you wind up searching the entire document when you are only interested in one item.

Also, both of those methods return "live" node lists which require re-scanning the entire document every time their results are referenced. The use cases for that are limited.

Instead use **[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** when you want to find just one item based on any valid CSS selector and **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** when you want to find a set of matching elements.

Assuming these things are corrected, you can do this:

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".selected td input[type=hidden]");
alert(x.value);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="selected">
    <td id="participantID">XXXXX1234
     <input type="hidden" value="000001234" id="taxID">
    </td>
    <td id="fullName">Y, X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is working now after removing ID of hidden field. Thank you for your valuable time sir.

Comment: @Nitesh You are welcome. But don't forget to correct the other issues I mention and don't forget to mark this as "the" answer.

Comment: It was working before reading your solution. But After reading your above comment, I tried your solution. Great job sir. I made some changes as per your suggestion. I added that input field inside <td> tag. Your answer was really helpful. I was unaware of getElementsByClassName() and getElementsByTagName(). Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge sir.

Comment: @Nitesh Again, you are welcome. It's important in web development to differentiate between "working" and "correct". There is a lot of code that may "work" in one or more browsers, but that does not mean that it is "correct" and will work in all browsers or work efficiently. Following standards (using valid code) and understanding the basic principles of the language / API will help in a huge way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `table` be the parent of a `tr`, then the DOM lookup will properly work. Also as noted by *@Rory McCrossan* you will want to wrap `td` tag around your `input` element:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[0];
var y = x.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
alert(y.value);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="selected">
    <td id="participantID">XXXXX1234</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="000001234" id="taxID" /></td>
    <td id="fullName">Y, X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is working now after removing ID of hidden field. Thank you for your valuable time sir.

Answer (score 0):

(Posted solution on behalf of the OP).

After removing ID of hidden field, it is working fine. Edited code is:

```
<tr class="selected">
<td id="participantID">XXXXX1234</td>
<input type="hidden" value="000001234" id="taxID">
<td id="fullName">Y, X</td>
</tr>
```